# Rxjava - isolation of logic

Tags: android, rx-java

Basically , I want to check if i have data in my DB, and if i dont have, make an api call. I'm using this logic for making the request to the API:

```
 private void requestDataToApi() {
        mSubscribe = createRequest()
                .delay(DELAY_SPLASH_SCREEN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(categoryModels -> {
                    writeDataToDb(categoryModels);

                }, (throwable -> {
                    dealError();
                }));
    }
```

And this logic to verify if there any data stored:

```
if (mRealm.where(CategoryModel.class).findAll().size() == 0) {
      requestDataToApi();
    } else {
      getView().openMainActivity(readDataFromDb());
    }
```

There is any way to join this both logics? Basically, be the dispose verifying the db and just make the call if needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use filter and switchIfEmpty operator

```
@Test
public void ifEmpty() throws InterruptedException {
    Observable.just(getDataFromDatabase())
            .filter(value -> !value.isEmpty())
            .switchIfEmpty(Observable.just("No data in database so I go shopping"))
            .subscribe(System.out::println);
}

private String getDataFromDatabase() {
    if(new Random().nextBoolean()){
        return "data";
    }
    return "";
}
```

You can learn more from reactive world here https://github.com/politrons/reactive

Comment: I'm getting a thread problem: OnError Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.
                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they were created.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need the [Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

What this pattern does it isolate the business logic from the data origin.  So you just ask for data and don'r care where this data come from. So you could hava something like:

```
public class CategoryModelRepo {

    public Observable<CategoryModel> getAll() {
        return Observable.defer(() -> {
            List<CategoryModel> fromRealm = mRealm.where(CategoryModel.class).findAll();
            if (fromRealm.size() == 0) {
                return requestDataToApi()
                    .onNext(dataList -> storeDataInRealm(dataList))
            } else {
                return Observable.just(fromRealm);
            }
        }
    }

    // This code fragment could be improved by applying a DAO pattern
    // http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html
    private Observable<CategoryModel> requestDataToApi() {
        return createRequest()
            .delay(DELAY_SPLASH_SCREEN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
```

So from your business layer (or, in your case, view layer) you can load the data to ensure it has been stored locally.

Don't forget to use `.subscribeOn(...)` and `.observeOn(...)` where necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to add one more dependency to your project, [Store](https://github.com/NYTimes/Store) is a (very) nice solution. Otherwise, I would recommend using concepts from the Repository pattern.